# Distance Estimation from Signal Level?

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, matlab, distance

So, I want to learn about machine learning and apply it to my project. I have set of data which includes position of a car and unknown emitter signal level. I have to estimate the distance based on this. Basically signal levels varies inversely to the square of distance. But when we include stuff like multipath,reflections etc we need to use a diff equation. Here come the Hata Okumura Model which can give us the path loss based on distance. However , the distance is unknown as I dont know where the emitter is. I only have access to different lat/long sets and the received signal level.

What I am asking is could you guys please guide me to techniques which would help me estimate the distance based on current pos and signal strength. I will look into it further.

Comment: This is probably too broad to be answerable here. You may want to edit this to make it more focused & concrete. You can also ask a series of questions as you come to understand each additional issue.

Comment: I will try to edit and make the question more concrete .

Comment: You can check book "Data Analysis: A Bayesian Tutorial" by Sivia and Skilling -- it describes example of estimating position of lighthouse by its signals in Bayesian approach.

Comment: Thanks I would look into this. I am also open to other solution and possibilities. I was looking at ML where I would feed it the signal strength and computed distance from current position to the unknown emitter while training. Note I wont know the actual distance in a unknown dataset ! Now once trained, my model could give me a distance estimation based on signal strength. Then I can take the distance estimation, and current position and compute the location of the emitter. Any thoughts on this ?